# Show that $\mathbb{E}[g(X)] \le \mathbb{E}[ g(Y)]$ where $g$ is convex, $X$ is binomial and $Y$ is poisson

Tags: probability, probability-theory, inequality

Let $X$ be a binomial random variable with parameter $\left(n,p\right)$, and let $Y$ be a Poisson random variable with parameter $np$. Let $g$ be a convex function. Prove that
$$\mathbb{E}[g(X)] \le \mathbb{E}[g(Y)]$$

What is the strategy here? I thought of Jensen's inequality, and that Binomial can be approximate by Poisson. But I don't know how to proceed. The hint asked me to consider a special case where $X\sim \text{Bin}(1,p)$ and $Y\sim\text{Bin}(2, p/2)$. I worked that out, but don't see how that helps.

Comment: How is $Y\sim\text{Bin}\left(2, p/2\right)$ a special case of a Poisson variable?

Comment: @LinAlg That is a very good question to which I have no answer.

Comment: @LinAlg : There is no suggestion here that $\operatorname{Bin}(2,p/2)$ is a special case of the Poisson distribution. Rather, it is suggested that considering that may shed some light.

Comment: @LinAlg : Although of course one would say that $\operatorname{Bin}(2,p/2)$ is one step closer to the Poisson distribution than $\operatorname{Bin}(1,p)$ is, and $\operatorname{Bin}(3,p/3)$ is another step closer, and so on.

Comment: @MichaelHardy That's basically what I'm trying to convey in my answer.

Comment: And the idea is not to approximate the binomial with the Poisson, but rather to approximate the Poisson with the binomial. That's what the hint says.

Comment: @MichaelHardy Umm... That's something didn't occur to me. Will work on that tonight.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**$^1$ generalize your special case to 
$$
X \sim \operatorname{Bin}(n,p), \qquad Y' \sim \operatorname{Bin}\left(k n,\frac{p}{k}\right)
$$
for any arbitrary integer $k\geq 1$.

Then use the [Poisson limit theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_limit_theorem) as $k\to\infty$.

---

$^1$ *If you try for a bit and are still stuck, leave a comment and I will fill in the details and work out a full derivation.*

Comment: I was working on the case where $X\sim \text{Bin}\left(1,p\right)$ and $Y\sim \text{Bin}\left(n, p/n\right)$, and the algebra is already very complicated. Basically I am trying to show that the coefficients in front of a certain power of $p$ would sum to $1$, after begin divided by the coefficient in front of $g(1)$. But maybe that is not the right way to do it?

Comment: @3x89g2 yes, that looks messy. I was trying to think of a slick way to do it: not sure it'll work, but since a $\operatorname{Bin}(n,p)$ is the sum of $n$ independent $\operatorname{Bin}(1,p)$, my hope is to write something like (beware, huge abuse of notation below between r.v.'s and distributions) $$\begin{align}\mathbb{E}[g(\textrm{Bin}(n,p)] &= \mathbb{E}[g(n\textrm{Bin}(1,p)]  \leq n\mathbb{E}[g(\textrm{Bin}(1,p)] \leq n\mathbb{E}[g(\operatorname{Bin}(2,p/2)] \\&\leq 2n\mathbb{E}[g(\operatorname{Bin}(1,p/2)] \leq\cdots \leq 4n\mathbb{E}[g(\operatorname{Bin}(1,p/4)] \end{align}$$

Comment: (or something in that spirit), to essentially bootstrap "for free" the case $\textrm{Bin}(1,p)$ vs. $\textrm{Bin}(2,p/2)$ to $\textrm{Bin}(n,p)$ vs. $\textrm{Bin}(2^k n,p/2^k)$.

Comment: Do you mind posting your full derivation for my reference? Thanks!